# MySQLi: SELECT all users that are NOT in the user logged in friend array

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to randomly select users from the dB that are not recognized as afriend in the current users (userLoggedIn) friend array.  I have users in the friend array tabled like this:

```
,edith_copecky,eddie_sasnchez,jay_beagle,red_one,
```

When I make calls to extract only those that are friends I use the following:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username' LIMIT 0,8");
```

but now I'm wanting to do the opposite and have them display randomly but am unsure how.

```
$not_friend_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ......???? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,5");
```

I'm fairly new to this so please go easy :)  I'm just not sure how to filter away  those members whom are already friends with the userLoggedIn, from the query result.

Comment: Do you have a database table which lists the friends of the logged in user, you can then use SQL to do the work for you.

Comment: You shouldn't use comma-separated lists in SQL. Normalize your schema.

Comment: you need to add a flg in your table as user get logged in, make that vlue 1 and as he gets logged out make that 0

Comment: And you shouldn't use `LIKE` to search comma-separated lists, use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: I do yes.  They are listed in the friend_array like ,edith_copecky, eddie_sasnchez,jay_beagle,   etc.  These are the usernames of friends of the current user Logged In.  So I want to select * users WHERE the username is not in the friend_array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all the users who are not in the current user's `friend_array`, you need a self-join. You need to use the `LEFT JOIN - NULL` pattern to find the users that *don't* match.

Use `FIND_IN_SET` to match a name against a comma-separated list, rather than your complicated set of `LIKE` patterns.

```
SELECT u1.username
FROM users AS u1
LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON FIND_IN_SET(u1.username, u2.friend_array) AND u2.username = '$userLoggedIn'
WHERE u2.username IS NULL
AND u1.username != '$userLoggedIn' -- exclude user themselves
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/TNEZ38594)

Comment: So it would be something like this?  `$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET('username', friend_array) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,5"); `

Comment: How would I exclude the userLoggedIn username from that query aswell?  The current users username will not be in the friend_array of course.  The query works, but I'm seeing the current users profile show up on random loads.  Could I add an AND statement?

Comment: Add `AND username != 'username'` (replace `username` with the correct name of the column).

Comment: hmmm...it seems that friends are still being returned in query.

Comment: `NOT FIND IN SET('username', friend_array)` is only looking to exclude the string var username.  I need it to exclude all usernames that are in the current users friend_array.

Comment: I thought you wanted to find everyone who is not a friend of a specific user in `$username`.

Comment: I do yes, everyone that is not a friend.  But username is not a variable $username.  It is the name of the column in user table.  My understanding is that ('username', friend_array) is only excluding the word username.

Comment: I thought you were replacing that with the name of the current logged in user.

Comment: If I replace that with the variable for the current logged in user I would use $userLoggedIn.  But I get a syntax error.  What I need the query to do is NOT FIND all the username (which is the column name) that are in the current users friend_array and return them randomly to a limit of 5.

Comment: I've added an online demo that shows that it works, no syntax error.

Comment: Subbing in this, I'm getting no return.  `$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT u1.username FROM users AS u1 LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON FIND_IN_SET(u1.username, u2.friend_array) AND u2.username = '$userLoggedIn' WHERE u2.username IS NULL AND u1.username != '$userLoggedIn' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5"); `  What I'm trying to return is a profile pic and username to display, but the error is now Undefined index: profile_pic etc.

Comment: Add that to what you select: `SELECT u1.username, u1.profile_pic`

Comment: whew! thankyou so much.  I wish I was as good as you someday ;)